# Overriding Hibernate ConnectionProvider in Spring Boot 2.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I am upgrading a kotlin Spring Boot 1.x application to use Spring Boot 2.1.6

Previously I used `EntityManagerFactoryBeanCallback` to set the `hibernate.connection.provider_class` to our custom implementation of `ConnectionProvider`. This was deprecated and removed in spring boot 2.0 and 2.1 respectively.

I am now attempting to use a `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer`

```
@Bean
fun hibernatePropertiesCustomizer() = HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
    it["hibernate.connection.provider_class"] = ScopedConnectionProvider::class.java.name
}
```

The application throws an error now:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    Caused by:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

        Caused by:
        org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

            Caused by:
            org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

If I comment out the `it["hibernate.connection.provider_class"] = ScopedConnectionProvider::class.java.name` line everything works except obviously the custom `ConnectionProvider`

For reference I am using the `ScopedConnectionProvider` to enable our multitenancy by setting a variable on each connection representing the customers scope ID. Any alternate solution that allows me to run a `SET @scope_id = ?` query on every connection would also be fine.

Relevant version information:

- Spring Boot: 2.1.6
- Spring: 5.1.8
- Hibernate: 5.3.10
- Kotlin: 1.3.21

Comment: Looking at the log, I think, if you set `hibernate.dialect` in your `hibernatePropertiesCustomizer`, the problem will be solved. Unfortunately, I don't know how to set it with Kotlin.

Comment: @Johna, I would rather not override that in the code if possible, I do not see how it is related to my ConnectionProvider and I never used to have to do that.

Comment: Does Hibernate know which DB-type you're trying to connect to? You're choosing a DB at some point; it looks like that choice is happening after this code is being loaded by Spring. Are you doing it programmatically (which is late) instead of in config (in your pom.xml or similar)? Since you're going with Spring Boot, the easiest thing is to use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) to pick you SQL dependency and select "Explore the Project" to grab the dependency that Spring uses to build the `hibernate.dialect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Datasource was not being injected into my `ScopedConnectionProvider` correctly anymore. I changed it so that I was inheriting from `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` instead of implementing my own `ConnectionProvider` from scratch. This seems to have removed the need to specify the dialect.